# Как развернуть текст на 180 градусов и поместить его в блок с иконками?

Tags: html, css, css3

Есть блок с социальнымии кнопками. Как правильно развернуть текст на 180 градусов относительно иконок как показано на картинке? У меня пока не получается увязать все в 1 блок, чтобы он был всегда слева относительно текста

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.rotatable {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-+d0P83n9kaQMCwj8F4RJB66tzIwOKmrdb46+porD/OvrJ+37WqIM7UoBtwHO6Nlg" crossorigin="anonymous">
<ul>
  <li class='rotatable'>
    &mdash;&mdash;&mdash; Follow us
  </li>
  <li><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></li>
  <li><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></li>
  <li><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></li>
  <li><i class="fab fa-pinterest"></i></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Смотреть на полном экране

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li, i {
  color: white;
}

ul {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #212121;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.rotatable {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  padding: 2rem 0;
}

li {
  padding: 1rem 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-+d0P83n9kaQMCwj8F4RJB66tzIwOKmrdb46+porD/OvrJ+37WqIM7UoBtwHO6Nlg" crossorigin="anonymous">
<ul>
  <li class='rotatable'>
    ——Follow us
  </li>
  <li><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></li>
  <li><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></li>
  <li><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></li>
  <li><i class="fab fa-pinterest"></i></li>
</ul>
```